# php get function argument length

Tags: php, function, arguments

I am wondering if you can get the argument length of a **php** functions arguments from an external scope.

```
$test = function($one, $two) {
  // this will work inside the scope of the function
  $length = func_num_args();
};
// I would like to access it from outside the functions scope
$length = get_arg_count(test); // => 2
```

If I `var_dump(test)` I can see a property on the Closure of `properties` but I can't get at it.

There is `func_num_args(void)` but that only works from inside the function scope.

I have tried...

```
test->properties;
test->properties();
test::properties;
test::properties();
test['properties'];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to [*reflect*](http://php.net/reflectionfunction) on the function:

```
$ref = new ReflectionFunction($test);
echo $ref->getNumberOfParameters();
```

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
$test = function($one, $two) {
    // this will work inside the scope of the function
    $length = func_num_args();

    var_dump($length); // => 2
};

var_dump($test);
```

result:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
object(Closure)#1 (1) {
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["$one"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
    ["$two"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
  }
}
```

if return function argument length, You can try [ReflectionFunction](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php)